# In Electron, can I access the console in a renderer process from the main process

Tags: console, electron

I am working on an [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) app where I'd don't control the contents of the render process. For this portion of the app, I'm just browsing a remote URL outside of the app.

I'd like to be able to stream the console from that render process to the main process and detect the presence of certain messages and act upon them in the main process.

Since I don't control the render process I can't use IPC to send messages. If I launch Electron with the `ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING` environment variable, I can stream the render process, but only to the terminal. I don't know how to access that data in the main electron process. Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best shot would be using `console-message` event in webContents. (https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-console-message)

It allows to hook console messages from certain webcontents' console, but mind there is one known issue of param for those consoles are not forwareded: i.e `console.log('message', ...args);` you'll likely not able to grab args.